# Assigning values to Pandas Multiindex DataFrame by index level

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a Pandas multiindex dataframe and I need to assign values to one of the columns from a series. The series shares its index with the first level of the index of the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
idx0 = np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo'])
idx1 = np.array(['one', 'two', 'three', 'one', 'one', 'two'])
df = pd.DataFrame(index = [idx0, idx1], columns = ['A', 'B'])
s = pd.Series([True, False, True],index = np.unique(idx0))
print df
print s
```

out:

```
             A    B
bar one    NaN  NaN
    two    NaN  NaN
    three  NaN  NaN
baz one    NaN  NaN
foo one    NaN  NaN
    two    NaN  NaN

bar     True
baz    False
foo     True
dtype: bool
```

These don't work:

```
df.A = s # does not raise an error, but does nothing
df.loc[s.index,'A'] = s # raises an error
```

expected output:

```
             A     B
bar one    True   NaN
    two    True   NaN
    three  True   NaN
baz one    False  NaN
foo one    True   NaN
    two    True   NaN
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Series (and dictionaries) can be used just like functions with map and apply (thanks to @normanius for improving the syntax):

```
df['A'] = pd.Series(df.index.get_level_values(0)).map(s).values
```

Or similarly:

```
df['A'] = df.reset_index(level=0)['level_0'].map(s).values
```

Results:

```
A    B
bar one     True  NaN
    two     True  NaN
    three   True  NaN
baz one    False  NaN
foo one     True  NaN
    two     True  NaN
```

Comment: I do wonder if this is a bug that it doesn't work if the values passed have index values that can be aligned, anyway +1

Comment: I couldn't figure out what the syntax should be using `.loc` either to assign the values, hopefully a better pandas person will appear to answer that. To me this should just work so there must be a way of doing this without resorting to `map`

Comment: Oh, I thought you were referring to something else.  I figure map is as good of a way to do this as any.  Could also do via merge, but I suspect that's a little slower (but maybe clearer to read).

Comment: @JohnE: I'd suggest to write `df['A'] = pd.Series(df.index.get_level_values(0)).map(s).values`, this is robust and a bit clearer than your example.

Comment: @normanius  Thanks!  I don't even remember answering this question but agree completely with your comment and have edited to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

> `df.A = s` does not raise an error, but does nothing

Indeed this should have worked.<sup>Your point is actually related to [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67953304/how-to-prevent-groupby-from-surclassing-index).</sup>

**ᐊᐊ** ***The workaround*** **ᐊᐊ**

```
>>> s.index = pd.Index((c,) for c in s.index)  # ᐊᐊᐊᐊᐊᐊᐊᐊ
>>> df.A = s
>>> df
               A    B
bar one     True  NaN
    two     True  NaN
    three   True  NaN
baz one    False  NaN
foo one     True  NaN
    two     True  NaN
```

---

***Why does the above work ?***

Because when you do directly `df.A = s` ***without the workaround***, you are actually trying to assign [`pandas.Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html)-contained coordinates within a subclass instance,<sup>which somehow looks like a "counter-opposition" to the [LS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)</sup> i.e. an instance of [`pandas.MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html). I mean, look for yourself:

```
>>> type(s.index).__name__
'Index'
```

whereas

```
>>> type(df.index).__name__
'MultiIndex'
```

Hence this workaround that consists in turning `s`'s index into a 1-dimensional [`pandas.MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) instance.

```
>>> s.index = pd.Index((c,) for c in s.index)
>>> type(s.index).__name__
'MultiIndex'
```

and nothing has perceptibly changed

```
>>> s
bar     True
baz    False
foo     True
dtype: bool
```

---

***A thought:*** From many views (mathematical, ontological) all this somehow shows that [`pandas.Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) should have been designed as a subclass of [`pandas.MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html), not the opposite, as it is currently.

Comment: @EdChum the above workaround may give you an idea of the type of bug that is currently at work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `join` method on the `df` DataFrame, but you need to name the indexes and the series accordingly:

```
>>> df.index.names = ('lvl0', 'lvl1')
>>> s.index.name = 'lvl0'
>>> s.name = 'new_col'
```

Then the join method creates a new column in the DataFrame:

```
>>> df.join(s)
              A    B  new_col
lvl0 lvl1
bar  one    NaN  NaN     True
     two    NaN  NaN     True
     three  NaN  NaN     True
baz  one    NaN  NaN    False
foo  one    NaN  NaN     True
     two    NaN  NaN     True
```

To assign it to an existing column:

```
>>> df['A'] = df.join(s)['new_col']
>>> df
                A    B
lvl0 lvl1
bar  one     True  NaN
     two     True  NaN
     three   True  NaN
baz  one    False  NaN
foo  one     True  NaN
     two     True  NaN
```