# Pandas - Merging resulting dataframe of apply function into new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to amortize the cost of a project linearly by month across the project length.

To do this I iterate over a dataframe of projects with a defined function that will turn each row (or project) into a new dataframe of cost schedules.

Then I would like the returned dataframes of my function to be merged together to create my final dataset as a list of billing schedules for all projects in my initial dataframe.

Here is my defined function:

```
    def amortizeProject(name, start, end, cost):
      """ Create an amortized cost schedule by month for a given project where:
        name = project Name
        start = start date of project
        end = end date of project
        cost = total cost of project
      """
      # Create an index of the payment dates
      rng = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='MS')
      rng.name = "Cost_Date"

      # Build up the Amortization schedule as a DataFrame
      df = pd.DataFrame(index=rng,columns=['Name','Period_Cost'], dtype='float')

      # Add index by period
      df.reset_index(inplace=True)
      df.index += 1
      df.index.name = "Period"
      df["Name"] = name
      df["Period_Cost"] = np.pmt(0, rng.size, cost)

      # Return the new dataframe
      df = df.round(2)
      return df
```

I'm attempting to iterate over my initial_dataframe, i.e.:

```
            Name       Start         End     Cost
    0  Project 1  2019-07-01  2020-07-01  1000000
    1  Project 2  2020-01-01  2021-03-31   350000
```

Using the function like so:

```
    new_dataframe = initial_dataframe.apply(lambda x: amortizeProject(x['Name'], x['Start'], x['End'], x['Cost']), axis=1)
```

Ideally, the new_dataframe would be the concatenation of all the resulting iterations but I'm not sure on the correct way to format the output of the .apply function to do this.  I do know that the function produces expected results for a single iteration.

Also, I'm pretty new to Pandas so if there is a better/more optimized way to do this, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended going with the following solution that worked for my need using a global dataframe:

```
globalDF = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Cost_Date','Name','Period_Cost'])
```

And then during the function iterations I use a concat function to build upon the global:

```
globalDF = pd.concat([globalDF,df])
```

This is very similar to the list append method provided.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest option may be a combination of `apply` and `stack`.. so use .apply along the rows to return a pd.Series (where the index are each date in the schedule, and the values are the amortized values), and then use `.stack` to collapse the values into their rightful places, e.g.

```py
def amortize(sers):
    values = #get the values
    dates = #get the dates
    return pd.Series(values, index=dates)

new_df = initial_dataframe.apply(amortize, axis=1).stack()
```

Comment: I've been playing around with this approach and I have a few issues.   The multiple columns from my function are important to the final results and I've actually simplified them in the example.   When trying to create a series, it's a bit challenging since it's not a single dimension.  I tried using a combination of pd.Series(df.to_dict), which allows me to stack but then i end up with a rather complex multidimensional object.  I'm not sure this solution will work for my use case, or I might not be applying it correctly.

Comment: The input series `sers` keeps the values from the columns in your original dataframe within the amortize function for whatever row is being processed at the time, since we're using the `axis=1` argument in the `apply`... I just replaced your args to make the function call look cleaner.  You can reference e.g. the 'Start' column within the `amortize` function using something like `start = sers.at['start']`.  All the `apply` does is return the date columns + amortized values, with null values where they don't apply.  The `stack` function is just to "unpivot" the date fields into a date column.

Comment: on your multidimensional issue... I dont know what your primary key is, but you're changing the shape of the dataframe, so figure out what that is and then have the dates be the final level in the index.  Then you can set the values you need with `reset_index(level=<level with dates>)` and then `assign` or just using `df = ...` .  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117838/assigning-values-to-pandas-multiindex-dataframe-by-index-level) for more info on that

Answer (score 1):

instead of formatting `.apply()`, I think you can achieve that through this:

Initialize an empty list for storing all your df, `df_list = []`. Populate it during iteration inside the function, `df_list.append(df)`. After iteration, concatenate all df stored in that list to df,`df = pd.concat(df_list)`.

So the code you posted should be:

```
def amortizeProject(name, start, end, cost):
  """ Create an amortized cost schedule by month for a given project where:
    name = project Name
    start = start date of project
    end = end date of project
    cost = total cost of project
  """
  # Create an index of the payment dates
  rng = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='MS')
  rng.name = "Cost_Date"

  # Build up the Amortization schedule as a DataFrame
  df = pd.DataFrame(index=rng,columns=['Name','Period_Cost'], dtype='float')

  # Add index by period
  df.reset_index(inplace=True)
  df.index += 1
  df.index.name = "Period"
  df["Name"] = name
  df["Period_Cost"] = np.pmt(0, rng.size, cost)

  # Return the new dataframe
  df = df.round(2)
  df_list.append(df)
  return df_list


df_list = []
new_dataframe = initial_dataframe.apply(lambda x: amortizeProject(x['Name'], x['Start'], x['End'], x['Cost']), axis=1)
df = pd.concat(df_list)
print(df)
```

The output should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFrEj.png)