# How to prevent groupby from surclassing index?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Say you have the following semi-[MultiIndex object](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'c': {
        ('r', 'r1'): 1.,
        ('r', 'r2'): 2.,
    },
})
print(df)
#       c
# r r1  1
#   r2  2
```

Let's focus on the hierarchical index, i.e. the vertical one. First, note that, as expected, we have

```
>>> df.index.__class__.__name__
'MultiIndex'
```

The point is that [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) may ***sur***-class `df.index` ***depending on whether the final number of levels is 1***.

```
>>> dfg = df.groupby(axis=0, level=0).sum()
>>> dfg.index.__class__.__name__
'Index'
```

***What is the cleanest way to prevent/correct such behavior ?*** For now, I go with

```
>>> dfg.index = pd.Index((c,) for c in dfg.index)  # Doing so is equivalent to using `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`
>>> dfg.index.__class__.__name__
'MultiIndex'
```

---

***Why ?***<sub>See comments: no XY problem ...</sub>

Say you want to "propagate" the summed values to lower levels.<sup>None of the solutions proposed on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) suits me. Not readable enough and/or hiding interesting transitory calculations.</sup> It turns out that when dealing at source ***and*** destination with instances of MultiIndex, performing such propagation becomes fairly easy.

```
>>> df_            = df.copy()  # copy for the sake of illustration
>>> df_.iloc[:, :] = dfg  # Actually equivalent to `df_.update(dfg)`
>>> df_
      c
r r1  3
  r2  3
# whereas without correction:
#        c
# r r1 nan
#   r2 nan
```

***NB***: this approach is valid for all `dfg.index.nlevels`.

Comment: May I ask what is your ultimate goal?  Is it to append this total to the original dataframe?

Comment: This seems a little in the `xy` direction. What are you looking for from an empty level 1 on axis 0?

Comment: And is there a reason against `transform`: `df.groupby(axis=0, level=0).transform('sum')`?

Comment: @HenryEcker Indeed, the result of `~.sum` may undergone some costly adjustments whose repetition is to be avoided. Especially `~.transform` which is basically implemented as a for loop. Furthermore, `dfg` is of first interest for many reasons.

Comment: @ScottBoston No. My ultimate goal is to propagate the (costly adjusted) values of `dfg` at the lower levels of millions of rows, while also using `dfg` as such in other independent calculations (wherein surclassing is incidentally not an issue).

Comment: Will `pd.DataFrame.align` work? `pd.concat(list(df.align(dfg, level=0)), axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`pd.DataFrame.align`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.align.html#pandas-dataframe-align):

```
df.align(dfg, level=0)
```

Output:

```
(        c
 r r1  1.0
   r2  2.0,
         c
 r r1  3.0
   r2  3.0)
```

Note: The tuple with each dataframe having the same indexing.

Then,

```
 pd.concat(list(df.align(dfg, level=0)), axis=1)
```

Then you can get concatenated dataframe like this:

```
        c    c
r r1  1.0  3.0
  r2  2.0  3.0
```

Comment: By opposition to mine, your approach does not generalize to `dfg.index.nlvels > 1` cases (raising `TypeError: Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous`), which I need, as outlined when I write *[...] depending on whether the final number of levels is 1.*

Comment: @keepAlive Point taken.  I think you have the better solution to your requirements.