# Strange (?) behaviour with pandas assignments aligning on MultiIndex index

Tags: python, pandas

Often in my work using pandas I want to make assignments to data frames (e.g. updating column values or creating a new column) where I want to align against one or several (but not all) the index level of the initial data frame.

Below is an example the illustrates the problem:

```
# EXAMPLES ON STRANGE (?) BEHAVIOUR IN PANDAS ASSIGNMENTS

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':np.random.rand(8)},
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
                      [('#1','A',1,'a'),('#1','A',1,'b'),
                      ('#1','A',2,'a'),('#1','A',2,'b'),
                      ('#1','B',1,'a'),('#1','B',1,'b'),
                      ('#1','B',2,'a'),('#1','B',2,'b')]
                  , names=['ID','Big','Num','Small']))
idx = pd.IndexSlice

# EX1
df['B'] = np.nan
df.loc[idx[:,:,:,'b'],'B'] = df.xs('a',level='Small')['A']
print(df)
# Works! Math on index levels 0,1,2

# EX2
df['B'] = np.nan
df.loc[idx[:,:,:,'b'],'B'] = df.xs((1,'a'),level=('Num','Small'))['A']
print(df)
# Works! Math on index levels 0,1

# EX3
df['B'] = np.nan
df.loc[idx[:,:,:,'b'],'B'] = df.xs(('A',1,'a'),level=('Big','Num','Small'))['A']
print(df)
# Does not work! Cant't match on index level 0 because .xs converts
# MultiIndex to Index when only one index level remains

# EX4
df['B'] = np.nan
df.loc[idx[:,:,:,'b'],'B'] = df.xs(1,level='Num')['A']
print(df)
# Does not work! Cant't match on index levels 0,1,3
```

Generally I solve the problems with some workaround usually involving .merge, .join or .reindex, but I haven't been able to find something that is intuitive and does not rely on extra lines of code.
So, my question is if you have some good ways to solve these problems or any information if these behaviours are considered wanted in pandas or if there is a chance of future updates solving this?

For EX3 there is a suggested workaround here, but I don't think this is very intuitive: [How to prevent groupby from surclassing index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67953304/how-to-prevent-groupby-from-surclassing-index)

All the best!

Comment: Why didn't you use: `df.loc[idx[:,:,:,'b'], 'B'] = df.loc[idx[:, 'A', 1, 'a'], 'A']`?

Comment: That does not work since 'a' != 'b'. And the behaviour I am looking for in EX3 is for it to match only on index level 0 ("ID") and propagate the values across the other levels, as is the behaviour in EX1 and EX2. This is why I use .xs to drop the index levels I used to slice.